# POE camera not working with POE switch (does not power on)

Tags: switch, ip-camera, power-over-ethernet, network-camera

I have a POE camera (DH-SD8A840VI-HNI) and a POE switch (Planet GS-5220-16UP4S2X)

However, the POE camera will not power on when connected to the switch, even when this camera is the only device connected. I have to set "force power = true" to the port that the camera is connected to for it to work.

I tried the following:
DH-SD8A840VI-HNI + Planet POE-171A-BT POE injector - OK
DH-SD8A840VI-HNI + Planet GS-5220-16UP4S2X (force power) - OK
Planet GS-5220-16UP4S2X + other brand 802.3bt camera - OK
Planet GS-5220-16UP4S2X + other brand 802.3af camera - OK

What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Dahua camera works with 40W+ Hi-POE injector (24v).
Maybe that's your problem.
Read this topic:
https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/ultra-ptz-comparison-sd8a840vi-hni-versus-sd6al830v-hni.34293/

Comment: The camera in questions requires 802.3bt, and the switch I have supports 802.3bt up to 90w per port... There is more than enough power!
In fact, if I use the force power option on the switch, the camera works fine. The problem is that it doesn't negotiate the poe automatically as expected like my other 802.3bt camera. Power draw from the camera is under 30w

Comment: It's possible that either or both, cam and switch, predate 802.3bt - they might not be entirely compatible with each other. Make sure you've got the latest firmware and in doubt, double check the manuals or contact vendor support to verify.